# What options do I have when performing RAG on similarly phrased chunks?

Tags: large-language-models, prompt, prompt-design, information-retrieval

I'm building a RAG pipeline to extract real estate phrases from excel documents. These phrases are short (2-5 words) and are often phrased differently.

I've manually added in different phrases to each prompt to suggest the LLM to look for them.

What else could I do? What more powerful options do I have?

- Search for each term manually? -> slow due to loads of calls
- Embed the terms in the excel doc and similarity search the embedding of 'Total Income' against those in the excel doc?

````
# Example prompt with 4 similar terms
income = f"""What is the Total Income? 

It may also be called: 
- Total Revenue
- Effective Gross Income
- Total Operating Receipts
- Total Operating Income

Or something similar

Return a signed number or nan. Do not write anything else."""
"""
```
````

Comment: If you know what keywords you're looking for, it might be easier to build an inverted index for keyword searching

Comment: @Karl can you please expand? What does building an inverted index involve? How would I do it? Code sample?

Comment: It's a database structure for fast text keyword searching
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/